# Is it possible to watch the ongoing cpu and memory usage of a running C++ app on a server linux distro?

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

I have developed a c++ app that runs on  debian jessie server. Since I'm quite new in linux distros and specially the server ones that provide only terminal, I 'd like to find out if there is a way to watch the %CPU and %MEM on the same time that the c++ app runs. I tried to run

```
./C++_APP & ps -aux | grep .C++_APP
```

but ps ran only at the beginning. Is this possible somehow either with ps or with another command?

Comment: Is it interactive app (needs input from user) or no?

Comment: @Anty . It does not input from user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`watch`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/watch). You can pass your `ps` (along with its arguments) to it. If you don't run your application as a background process you will have to use a second terminal session or pipe the results to a file that you can look at later on.

Comment: sorry for my perhaps silly question but is it possible  on a server distro to use a second terminal session ?

Comment: I would say it more likely for mutliple terminal sessions to be used on a server then on a desktop distroy. ;) If you have direct access to the system, you can use the multiple virtual consoles (see [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/111417/how-to-multitask-in-the-linux-terminal-3-ways-to-use-multiple-shells-at-once/)). If it's remote access you have to deal with you have to specify in your question how you access the system. SSH for example allows multiple sessions (unless some configuration restricts that).

Comment: Also the comment made by @Anty is a pretty valid one - you need to also give us information on whether `xserver` is required or not. My answer is valid for both but there are some changes required for example when using `ssh` if your system is a remote one.

Comment: for the time beeing I'm trying it on a VM but I'm going to use it on a cubietruck as well  that will be accessed by ssh.

Comment: So there should be no problem. Give it a go and do tell.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Is this the problem resolved? I see you have marked my answer.

Comment: Yes with the use of watch and a second virtual terminal everything worked fine

Answer (score 1):

You can use/install htop.
Set filter to match your executable name.

Answer (score 0):

You may try that:

```
./C++_APP & wait && PID=`pidof -s -x C++_APP` && top -b -p $PID
```

It will display stats every second.
To break CTRL+C

To kill your app type than

```
kill $PID
```